# Style select-values of simple products within a bundle product

Tags: bundled-product, simple-product, select

I am using simple products within my bundled products. As there are multiple Options I do get a select-list, that's not really well readable. An actual example is something like that:

```
<option value="128">Jeans Name -46-grey_black &nbsp; +44,99&nbsp;€</option>
```

This code says:

```
"Simple Products' title"+"-"+size-attribute+"-"color-attribute-code+" &nbsp; +"+Final Price
```

I'd love to have that a bit more readable. By saying this:

```
"Simple Products' title"+" The size: "+size-attribute+" The color: "color-attribute-name+" &nbsp; +"+Final Price
```

I output the option values by this code coming from the select.phtml

```
<?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>"<?php if ($this->_isSelected($_selection)) echo ' selected="selected"' ?><?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?>><?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, false) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Where would I need to change things to get this change done?
Thanks!